# Cryptographic Exception Unhandled (Cannot recognize byte key in encryption?)

Tags: c#, encryption, hash

I am new to C#, and I have encountered a cryptographic exception when trying to simply encrypt and decrypt a simple string. For the key, I used the SHA512 hash of the phrase "Pyber". This seems to be the problem as that the key (which is Pyber) is not an appropriate size.

When in debugging, I get this:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Have now tried to use MD5, enryption works very well while decryption still throws the same exception.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ENC_1
 {
    public partial class main : Form
    {
        public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string hash = "Pyber";

    private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Don't do anything
    }

    private void btn_encrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txt_input.Text);
        using (SHA512CryptoServiceProvider SHA512 = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            byte[] keys = SHA512.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
            {
                ICryptoTransform transform = tripDes.CreateEncryptor();
                byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                txt_encrypt.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(results, 0, results.Length);
            }
        }

    }

    private void btn_decrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(txt_encrypt.Text);
        using (SHA512CryptoServiceProvider SHA512 = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            byte[] keys = SHA512.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
            {
                ICryptoTransform transform = tripDes.CreateDecryptor();
                byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                txt_encrypt.Text = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(results);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to .Net support document, TripleDes accepts keys [between 128 and 192 bits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalkeysizes(v=vs.110).aspx), i.e. 16 and 24 chars.

SHA512 generates a 64 char keys; I suggest you try truncating your key to 24 chars,

```
byte[] newKey= new byte[24];
Array.Copy(keys, newKey, newKey.Length);
```

Comment: No, changing it to 24 characters doesn't seem to work with SHA512. I did, however, try to use MD5 instead,and it ended up successfully encrypting the string, but the decryption was unsuccessful. The same exception appeared -Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for feedback and happy that you achieve exptected result

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Reverting the hashing algorithm to MD5 turned out to work.